# Post Value of Select Disable Option

Tags: html, post

I want to post value when the user don't select the option, but

```
<select name="nowEdu_level" class="form-control">
    <option disabled="" selected="" value="0"></option> //this is the Disable Option
    <option value="level_bacDe">Bachelor Degree</option>
    <option value="level_masDe">Master Degree</option>
    <option value="level_other">Other Graduate</option>
</select>
```

But when I submit this post value is "None" , I want to post the "0" when the user don't select the option

please help me , I'm so beginner

Comment: using angular 2+ or 1

Comment: @T.Shashwat What makes you think this is Angular-related at all?

Answer (score 0):

When you click Post you will get the value 0 , have used getElementById to fetch vale by ID of dropdown.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<form>
Select your favorite fruit:
<select id="mySelect" name="nowEdu_level" class="form-control">
<option disabled="" selected="" value="0"></option> //this is the Disable Option
<option value="level_bacDe">Bachelor Degree</option>
<option value="level_masDe">Master Degree</option>
<option value="level_other">Other Graduate</option>
</select>
</form>

<p>Click the button to return the value of the selected fruit.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Post</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: If that what you looking for

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
 debugger;
 var e = document.getElementById("mySelect");
 var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
 console.log(strUser);
 }
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
Select your favorite fruit:
<select id="mySelect" name="nowEdu_level" class="form-control">
<option disabled="" selected="" value="0" ></option> //this is the Disable Option
<option value="level_bacDe">Bachelor Degree</option>
<option value="level_masDe">Master Degree</option>
<option value="level_other">Other Graduate</option>
</select>
</form>

<p>Click the button to return the value of the selected fruit.</p>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Post</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

This will give you a value of default selected item.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<select name="nowEdu_level" class="form-control">
    <option disabled selected value="">-- Education Level -- </option> //this is the Disable Option
    <option value="level_bacDe">Bachelor Degree</option>
    <option value="level_masDe">Master Degree</option>
    <option value="level_other">Other Graduate</option>
    <option value="0">None Above</option>
</select>
```

You can do like this